# Why is my code returning '()' despite returning the required value?

Tags: rust

Here is my code:

```
fn fetch_transaction (graph: &mut Vec<(&'static str, Transaction)>, tx_id: &'static str) -> Transaction {
    for item in graph.iter() {
        if item.0 == tx_id {
            return item.1;
        } else {
            println!("Transaction not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, item.1 is a Transaction struct type, while item.0 is a static string. When I compile it, I get this error:

```
fn fetch_transaction (graph: &mut Vec<(&'static str, Transaction)>, tx_id: &'static str) -> Transaction {
   |                                                                                               ----------- expected `Transaction` because of return type
54 | /     for item in graph.iter() {
55 | |         if item.0 == tx_id {
56 | |             return item.1;
57 | |         } else {
58 | |             println!("Transaction not found.");
59 | |         }
60 | |     }
   | |_____^ expected struct `Transaction`, found `()`
```

[image]
[image]

Why is this, and how can I fix it.

Comment: What should this function return when `item.0 != tx_id` for all `item`s?

Comment: I'd recommend you strongly when you face an error you don't understand to check the full error of `cargo check`. It is usually much easier.

Comment: @Cerberus "Transaction not Found"

Comment: @user404 printing something is not the same as returning something

Comment: Welp, do you think that could be the problem? I have tried excluding it and I got the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is possible that the vector does not contain an item whose `item.0` is `tx_id`, what you probably want to do is return an Option, which will be `None` if nothing was found.

Something like this:

```
fn fetch_transaction(graph: &mut Vec<(&'static str, Transaction)>, tx_id: &'static str) -> Option<Transaction> {
    graph.iter().find(|i| i.0 == tx_id).and_then(|i| Some(i.1))
}
```

Comment: I also added #[derive(Clone)] on top of the struct source file and used ".clone()" after Some(i.1). This has gotten my code to work properly.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the Some() part when printing?

Comment: You want to print the content of an Option? You can use something like `if let`, in order to get the content of the Option if it is a Some(transaction).